# What kind of history events can only be performed by moderators?

Tags: support, edits, moderator-tools, revisions-list

There are the following post history types (from SEDE):

1. Initial Title - The first title a question is asked with.
2. Initial Body - The first raw body text a post is submitted with.
3. Initial Tags - The first tags a question is asked with.
4. Edit Title - A question's title has been changed.
5. Edit Body - A post's body has been changed, the raw text is
   stored here as markdown.
6. Edit Tags - A question's tags have been changed.
7. Rollback Title - A question's title has reverted to a previous
   version.
8. Rollback Body - A post's body has reverted to a previous version

   - the raw  text is stored here.
9. Rollback Tags - A question's tags have reverted to a previous
   version.
10. Post Closed - A post was voted to be closed.
11. Post Reopened - A post was voted to be reopened.
12. Post Deleted - A post was voted to be removed.
13. Post Undeleted - A post was voted to be restored.
14. Post Locked - A post was locked by a moderator.
15. Post Unlocked - A post was unlocked by a moderator.
16. Community Owned - A post has become community owned.
17. Post Migrated - A post was migrated.
18. Question Merged - A question has had another, deleted question
    merged into  itself.
19. Question Protected - A question was protected by a moderator
20. Question Unprotected - A question was unprotected by a moderator
21. Post Disassociated - An admin removes the OwnerUserId from a
    post.
22. Question Unmerged - A previously merged question has had its
    answers and votes restored.

**Which of these types of edits can *only* be performed by moderators on Meta Stack Exchange?**

Note: clearly 1, 2, and 3 can be done by the question author, 4, 5, and 6 can be done by anyone, and 19 and 20 by moderators. What about the rest?

Comment: 19 and 20 can also be done by users with the [protect questions privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a big list:

#### CMs (community managers):

**21:** Post Disassociated - An admin removes the OwnerUserId from a
post.
**22:** Question Unmerged - A previously merged question has had its
answers and votes restored.
**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (any site, can be old more than 60 days, question only)

#### Privileged users, Moderators and CMs:

**10:** Post Closed - A post was voted to be closed.
**11:** Post Reopened - A post was voted to be reopened.
**12:** Post Deleted - A post was voted to be removed.
**13:** Post Undeleted - A post was voted to be restored.
**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated.
  (not possible in Meta Stack Exchange by non-diamond users,
  only to a small list of sites, must not be older than 60 days, question only)
**35:** Post Migrated Away

#### Moderators and CMs (MSE Only):

**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (any site, must not be older than 60 days, question only)
**35:** Post Migrated Away

#### Moderators and CMs:

**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (any site, must not be older than 60 days, question only)
**35:** Post Migrated Away

#### Moderators and CMs:

**16:** Community Owned - A post has become community owned.
**31:** Discussion moved to chat
**33:** Post Notice Added
**34:** Post Notice Removed

#### System (triggered by question merge):

**37:** Post Merge Source
**38:** Post Merge Destination

#### System:

**25:** Post Tweeted
**50:** CommunityBump - Community user bumps the question to the homepage
**52:** SelectedHotNetworkQuestion - Selected as a hot network question

#### System, moderators and CMs:

**53:** RemovedHotNetworkQuestion - Removed from HNQ

#### The owner of the post (answers only):

**16:** Community Owned - A post has become community owned.

#### Revisions which are created when a post is posted:

**1:** Initial Title - The first title a question is asked with. (question only)
**2:** Initial Body - The first raw body text a post is submitted with.
**3:** Initial Tags - The first tags a question is asked with. (question only)

#### Anyone:

**4:** Edit Title - A question's title has been changed.
**5:** Edit Body - A post's body has been changed, the raw text is
stored here as markdown.
**6:** Edit Tags - A question's tags have been changed.

#### The users with the Edit Posts privilege (the edit community wiki privilege for community wiki posts), the owner of the post, Moderators and CMs:

**7:** Rollback Title - A question's title has reverted to a previous
version.
**8:** Rollback Body - A post's body has reverted to a previous version
  - the raw  text is stored here.
**9:** Rollback Tags - A question's tags have reverted to a previous
version.
**24:** Suggested Edit Applied (moderators or post owners can override the decision and reject a approved edit or approve a rejected edit if no edits are made to the post after the suggested edit is suggested)

#### The users with the Protect Questions privilege, Moderators and CMs (question only):

**19:** Question Protected - A question was protected by a moderator
**20:** Question Unprotected - A question was unprotected by a moderator

#### Moderators and CMs (if the rollback or edit added or removed a moderator only tag):

**9:** Rollback Tags - A question's tags have reverted to a previous
version.
**6:** Edit Tags - A question's tags have been changed.

Comment: Hm. What's the difference between the MSE type 17 and the vanilla one?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek only mods can migrate questions on MSE, but on other sites all 3kers can vote to migrate.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard Users can only vote to migrate if there are migration targets. There are none on MSE - or on beta sites and even some graduated sites.

Comment: From where did you obtain this information? Can you cite a source, please?

Comment: @CodyGray Most of these are from the help center, other random questions that I don't remember, some comments and the data explorer. Most of the description of the revision types are stated in the question. I made up the rest of the history event descriptions.

Comment: Please note that I edited this answer for reasons of accessibility. In the previous revisions users with screenreaders couldn't access the answer, so I was told.

Answer (score 3):

The following can only be done by ♦ moderators (and employees who have a diamond):

**14:** Post Locked - A post was locked by a moderator.
**15:** Post Unlocked - A post was unlocked by a moderator.
**18:** Question Merged - A question has had another, deleted question merged into itself.

The following can only be done by ♦ moderators (and employees who have a diamond) on *questions*:

**16:** Community Owned - A post has become community owned.
**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (Meta Stack Exchange only)

The following cannot be done by ♦ moderators:

**17:** Post Migrated - A post was migrated. (if older than 60 days)
**21:** Post Disassociated - An admin removes the OwnerUserId from a post.
**22:** Question Unmerged - A previously merged question has had its answers and votes restored.

Comment: Also certain types of tag edits, on meta sites such as this one.